# How to make sticky header with colorful effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to make a **sticky header** as similar this site fcinq.com
But I am little bit confused about The **navbar** and menu **color style**. 
I take I container in header and divide it into 2 parts but I cann't able to make the **sticky header** as like fcinq.com

So How can I make same header as like fcinq.com ??
Site link: https://www.fcinq.com/

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-bottom: 200px;">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#about">Jhon Budy</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background: blue;/*! margin-bottom: 68px; */">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li class="current" style="margin-top: 102px;margin-bottom: 60px;"><a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#work">Work</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>


      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: "sticky header as like"....as like what? Your sentence ends without explaining anything. Also I think your snippet is missing some things (e.g. CSS and maybe bootstrap JS) as it doesn't seem to do anything much. It's hard to see what the issue is. Please edit your question to be clearer and give us an example we can see and understand. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry there was a link but somehow that was missing. Sticky header as similar like this site https://www.fcinq.com/

Comment: Do u understand now? Can u help me @ADyson sir??

Comment: Please also make your snippet usable, as I suggested. right now if you run it there's no header at all. Include appropriate CSS either inline or from a suitable CDN. Also has it occurred to you that you can simply use your browser's developer tools to look at the site you want to copy and there you can see _exactly_ how they did it, and apply the same thing to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like you are using bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top

change your nav code to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but still as best i can understand you can include the below css directly and modify the content according to you need. Include `<header></header>` in your `index.html`.

```
header {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1111;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 28px;
height: 28px;
line-height: 28px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background: #24397a;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 6px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
text-transform: capitalize;
display: none;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

You can also include other elements within header `tag` like anchor tags, logo etc.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Understood! you can go with window.scroll  and can add/remove class accoring to your need. For better understanding you can refer to [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fiddle for sticky header
https://jsfiddle.net/Nethravathi/y7x9vost/1/

```js
$(function(){
    $('.navbar').affix({
      offset: {
        /* Affix the navbar after scroll below header */
        top: $("header").outerHeight(true)}
    });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);

/* To mantain the navbar at the bottom*/
header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height:calc(100vh - 52px);
}


/* To mantain the navbar at the top once it is affixed */
.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

/* Padding for a smoth affix */
.affix + .container-fluid {
  padding-top: 72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class='container-fluid'>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac neque et sem molestie scelerisque.<br/>In felis sem, pharetra ornare mi et, mattis rhoncus est.<br/>Fusce id nulla et enim molestie fermentum sed ullamcorper nibh. </p>
</header>

<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
      <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
        <span class='sr-only'>Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        <span class='icon-bar'></span>
      </button>
      <a href='#' class='navbar-brand'> Title</a>
    </div>

    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse'>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href=''>Link</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Link</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Link</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac neque et sem molestie scelerisque.<br/>In felis sem, pharetra ornare mi et, mattis rhoncus est.<br/>Fusce id nulla et enim molestie fermentum sed ullamcorper nibh. </p>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac neque et sem molestie scelerisque.<br/>In felis sem, pharetra ornare mi et, mattis rhoncus est.<br/>Fusce id nulla et enim molestie fermentum sed ullamcorper nibh. </p>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac neque et sem molestie scelerisque.<br/>In felis sem, pharetra ornare mi et, mattis rhoncus est.<br/>Fusce id nulla et enim molestie fermentum sed ullamcorper nibh. </p>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac neque et sem molestie scelerisque.<br/>In felis sem, pharetra ornare mi et, mattis rhoncus est.<br/>Fusce id nulla et enim molestie fermentum sed ullamcorper nibh. </p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually I want to make the header as like this web site fcinq.com